# Find occurrence of a digit in a number

Tags: java

I am writing a program in which user will enter a digit `a` and find the number of times `a` will occur in another number `b` entered by the user.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    class Number
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            System.out.println("Enter the digit to match");
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            int a=s.nextInt();  //Digit whose occurrence is to find
            System.out.println("Enter the number to match");
            int b=s.nextInt(); //Number in which occurrence is to find
            int ctr=0;
            int ctr1=0;
            while(b!=0) //Number of digits in the entered number
            {
                b/=10;
                ctr++;
            }
            int arr[]=new int[ctr];
            for(int i=0;i<ctr;i++)  //Breaking the number into array of digits
            {
                arr[i]=b%10;
                b/=10;
                if(arr[i]==a)
                {
                    ctr1++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Number of occurrences are " +ctr1);
        }
    }
```

Each and every time the output is 0. Where I am wrong?

Comment: Is the first number in 0 to 9 range?

Comment: `a=121` and `b=121211211212` what will be output?

Comment: Yes, the first number if in 0-9 range. Now i am wondering how to solve this a=121 and b=121211211212

Answer (score 3):

after executing this cycle

```
        while(b!=0) //Number of digits in the entered number
        {
            b/=10;
            ctr++;
        }
```

b becomes 0 and thus it contains no digit but 0.

You need to store the value of b in some variable and re-initialize it after this cycle and before iterating over the digits. Alternatively use only a single cycle of the first type - you don't actually use the number of digits anywhere.

EDIT: another approach would be to convert the number to string and then use [lastIndexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int,%20int)) on it to find where the given digit is found. The performance will be a bit worse, but the code will be easier to understand(and shorter).

Comment: Thanks, Ivaylo. It worked. I reinitialized b and its working perfect now :)

Answer (score 1):

Something in the lines of:

```
int count=0;
char a = (char)(47 + s.nextInt());
char[] b = s.nextInt().ToString().ToCharArray();

for(int i=0; i < b.lenght(); i++)
{
   if(b[i]==a)
   {
     count++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Idea is that readability and simplicity are important features of your code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: Note this example is written from head and not tested.

Comment: Thanks Margus. Just re-initialized b and got the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

One basic error that I can find is that you have modified b to get the number of digits and so you can not get the individual bits from that now.

Try copying it into a separate variable before modifying the value of b.

Answer (score -1):

When this is executed, b is always 0.

```
arr[i]=b%10;
```

Comment: This answer is not useful.

Comment: Yea got it, reinitialized it :) Thanks